# MVC only alow admin login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I am working on a MVC5 EF6 database in Visual Studio 2013. The database is using Individual User Accounts for authentication with user roles.

In IIS it is possible to get the entire site down (e.g. for maintenance) by putting the `app_offline.htm` file. After I have updated the site and maybe migrated the database, as administrator I would like to perform some tests on the production machine before allowing all other users to login.

Is there a simple way to lockout all users except administrator from logging in until the administrator allows them to login ?

It would be nice if a similar construction can be used as the `app_offline.htm` file.

Below the code of the login method.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

I can imagine it would be possible to add some code in case `Success` to logout the user (if not memeber of administrators) and redirect to a special "logins temporary disabled" page. However, there might be better (or builtin) alternatives.

**Edit:**

I tried the filtes and they do not work as I expected. However, I will keep filters in mind to test with if I have some more time to do so.

For now I use the following code in the login method

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}

ApplicationUser au = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);

// If user is found and not member of administrators
if (au != null && !UserManager.IsInRole(au.Id, "Administrator"))
{
    // Check if the adminmode file exisits in the root. If so, redirect to it
    String adminModeFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "app_adminmode.htm");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(adminModeFilePath))
    {
        return new FilePathResult(adminModeFilePath, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    }
}

// This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
// To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

For `"Administrator"` and `"app_adminmode.htm"` I actually use constants which are declared in a central place, but for SO completeness I use the string here. If the user trying to login exists and is not in role Administrator, I will check the file. If the file exists the user is not logged in, but redirected

Comment: You could create a global filter that check if the application is in _test mode_. If in that case, check if the user is an admin and if not, redirect to your app_offline file. And to tag your application as _test mode_, maybe use an appSetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a check to see if the user is an admin sounds ok to me.

The only thing I would change though, is to add some kind of boolean flag to enable/disable the restrictions, and place this in your web.config file, so you don't need to modify your code and re-upload it to enable/disable access.

Add the following into your web.config, `<appSettings>` section:

`<add key="SystemLive" value="true" />`

Then within your login function, add:

```
if(!ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SystemLive"])
{
    return View("logins_temporary_disabled_page");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using the Authorize Attribute in FilterConfig.cs:

```
if(!ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SystemLive"])
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute{Roles = "Adminsitrator"});
}
else
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Edit: Thanks @gavin-coates be sure to Allow Anonymous on the login page or any page that should be accessible by un-uathenticated users.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
  public ActionResult Login() {
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: be careful where you add this though. If you add it to the login function, then you wouldn't be able to log in :)

Comment: I tried this, but I still can login with a username that is not member of the `Administrators` role. All my controllers have the `[Authorize]` attribute set on class level (except the home controller). the login was already set to allow Anonymous access.

Comment: You cant just use the [Authorize] attribute though. it needs to be constrained by Role - Otherwise anyone can login. You may find your local class attribute are overriding the global filter. Try removing you local class attributes and just use the global. - See my update to the global filter. You will need to add the [AllowAnonymous] to any public pages though. because everything will be locked out by default, except those pages with [AllowAnonymous].

Comment: Indeed if I remove the `[Authorize]` attribute the filter is added and I get the ugly (default) forbidden page. I do this with a file similar to the `app_offline.htm` file. When I remove the file, the filter is not reset. I am sure that can also be done by creating custom Authorize attribute, but for now I will use @GavinCoates solution. Putting the file in the root then will be detected at login and any user trying to login without proper roles assigned, will be redirected to that file (which is a nice page showing logins have been disabled)

Comment: If you are un-authorized then it will redirect to the login page (how do you end up at the forbidden page?). Are you sure you have [AllowAnonymous] on the GET and POST of the login page? Have you set  <authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /></authentication> in your web.config?

Comment: @MichaelLake, I start to better understand the filters. When a user tries to login in admin mode he/she will get the forbidden page as everything is restricted to role administrator. I want when the user tries to login, he/she is not logged in but redirected to a special page where is stated that user logins are disabled. I do not see how the filter can do the redirection. It will only restrict login to users in administrator role.

Comment: Ok - I see, your saying you have a requirement for the user to attempt the login. You want the site to appear normal until they try to login. That is fair enough.